# Tier prices are not applied on adding to cart

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, tierprice

I have set tier prices on products. while adding to cart the price should be like attached screenshot. Normal price is `30` while for 2 it will become `29.5` but after adding to cart it still shows `30 for each quantity (Tier prices not working). I am using Magento`2.2.4`. There is no related log, So I have no idea where is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Already run the reindex command with deployment and compile etc.No change